# Server Error with GAE Images Python API

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I try to use the Google App Engine example [Using the Images Python API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages) but run into a server error. I have tried changing the code but feel like the original version should be working. Does anybody know whats wrong?

I get the following error (XXXXX representing my application ID):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXXXX/1.377139462267655901/main.py", line 35, in get
    for greeting in greetings:
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2326, in next
    return self.__model_class.from_entity(self.__iterator.next())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1438, in from_entity
    return cls(None, _from_entity=entity, **entity_values)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 970, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 614, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2845, in validate
    % (self.name, type(value).__name__))
BadValueError: Property author must be a str or unicode instance, not a User
```

My main.py code is:

```
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import images
from google.appengine.api import users


class Greeting(db.Model):
    """Models a Guestbook entry with an author, content, avatar, and date."""
    author = db.StringProperty()
    content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    avatar = db.BlobProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=None):
    """Constructs a Datastore key for a Guestbook entity with guestbook_name."""
    return db.Key.from_path('Guestbook', guestbook_name or 'default_guestbook')


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        guestbook_name=self.request.get('guestbook_name')

        greetings = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * '
                                'FROM Greeting '
                                'WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 '
                                'ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10',
                                guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

        for greeting in greetings:
            if greeting.author:
                self.response.out.write(
                    '<b>%s</b> wrote:' % greeting.author)
            else:
                self.response.out.write('An anonymous person wrote:')
            self.response.out.write('<div><img src="img?img_id=%s"></img>' %
                                    greeting.key())
            self.response.out.write('<blockquote>%s</blockquote></div>' %
                                    cgi.escape(greeting.content))

        self.response.out.write("""
              <form action="/sign?%s" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
                <div><label>Avatar:</label></div>
                <div><input type="file" name="img"/></div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
              </form>
              <hr>
              <form>Guestbook name: <input value="%s" name="guestbook_name">
              <input type="submit" value="switch"></form>
            </body>
          </html>""" % (urllib.urlencode({'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}),
                        cgi.escape(guestbook_name)))


class Image(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        greeting = db.get(self.request.get('img_id'))
        if greeting.avatar:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
            self.response.out.write(greeting.avatar)
        else:
            self.response.out.write('No image')


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name')
        greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

        if users.get_current_user():
            greeting.author = users.get_current_user().nickname()

        greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
        avatar = images.resize(self.request.get('img'), 32, 32)
        greeting.avatar = db.Blob(avatar)
        greeting.put()
        self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(
            {'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/img', Image),
                               ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                              debug=True)
```

My app.yaml code is (XXXXX representing my application ID):

```
application: XXXXX
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

# [START libraries]
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
# [END libraries]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `db.UserProperty` and not a `db.StringProperty` for author in your model class. See [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore) the complete example.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now. Does that mean the code at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, it seems it's incorrect. If my answer helped you can accept it to close the question.